# BackboneJS before fetch event

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a collection ( using the Backbone.paginator ) that fetchs a array of models from the server and return to me. This collection is used on my "main view" and on "subviews". In each of these views I have a on("change") event that, in each view, does a particulary thing. I was thinking if I can listen to some "start fetch" event ( similar to the beforeLoad on the jquery) to add a loader gif. Does Backbone provide one of this?

If not.. How can I extend it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the Backbone Collection prototype like this:

```
(function() {
  var fetch = Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch;
  Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch = function() {
    this.trigger('beforeFetch');
    return fetch.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Now you can do something like:

```
myCollection.on('beforeFetch', function() {
  // take care of before fetch business
});
```

Answer (score 16):

Just use the event "request". It fires when a model (or collection) has started a request to the server.  It is available since version 0.9.9.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add a call to some method that sets the loading screen before each fetch call:

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.displayNormal)
this.displayLoader();
this.collection.fetch();
```

This should get you started. If you need that event (I can see why you would), you can override fetch like this

```
fetch: function() {
  this.trigger('beforeFetch');
  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is display the loading image when you call fetch, then set the success callback for fetch to hide it again.